# Compute the fundamental group of this space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Problem:** Let be:
$$A=\{ M \in \mathcal{M}(2\times 2,\mathbb{R}): \det(M)>0, \mbox{ such that at least a column of } M \mbox{ has positive entries } \}$$

Compute the fundamental group of $A$ endowed with the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^4$ where $\mathbb{R}^4$ is endowed with the euclidean norm.

**Attempt:**
I would like to prove that we can retract $A$ to $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ because of the fact that $\det (M)>0$ for all $M \in A$ but I am not sure if this is true or not. Here we denote $SL_2(\mathbb{R})=\{M \in \mathcal{M}(2\times 2,\mathbb{R}) : \det(M)=1 \}$. But as has been noted in the comments $SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \not \subset A$.

Comment: What is $SL(2\times2,\Bbb R)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I mean $SL(2\times2,\Bbb R)=\{M \in \mathcal{M}(2\times 2,\mathbb{R}) : \det(M)=1 \}$

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini Be careful, $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not a subspace of $A$.

Comment: Then the correct notation is $SL(2,\Bbb R)$, or $SL_2(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you, I wrote it in the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I edited the question with the correct notation.

Comment: If I got the cryptic phrase "at least a column of M has positive entries" correctly then I get that $A$ is contractible in quite a stupid way. Can it be the answer?

Comment: @КряжевАрсений Could you please explain it?

Comment: I feel that I got it wrong, since I don't get the point of the problem then. I thought: you have two vectors (columns), and one of them is in the first quadrant, while the other is less than $\pi$ away from it. Divide them by their lengths (that's deform. retr.) and draw a picture on the torus. You didn't answer my question though.